# Cannot receive IR codes after sending IR on same Arduino (I have irrecv.enableIRIn();)

Tags: arduino-uno, ir

I have two Arduinos with identical wiring, they will (hopefully) end up being laser guns for my younger cousins.

When they both have a sketch which simply toggles lights when the correct IR code is received, everything works as it should. see the code here:

// Start of sketch 1

```
#include <IRremote.h>
IRsend irsend; //Setup the IR transmitter
int receiver = 8; //initialize pin 13 as receiver pin.
IRrecv irrecv(receiver); //create a new instance of receiver
decode_results results;

// declare consants
const int trigger = 13;
const int greenLight = 7;
const int yellowLight = 2;
const int timeBetweenTransmittion = 800;

// declare variables
bool toggleGreen = true;
bool toggleYellow = true;
long int previousTransmittion = 0;

// put your setup code in here, to run once:
void setup() 
{
  pinMode(trigger, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600); // send code at 9600 bits per second
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // start the receiver
}

// put your main code in here, to run repeatedly:
void loop() {
  if (not digitalRead(trigger) && millis() > previousTransmittion + timeBetweenTransmittion) // if the button is pressed and it's been enought time since the last transmittion
  { 
    Serial.println("send!");
    irsend.sendNEC(1367857, 32); // send the code
    irrecv.enableIRIn(); // sending ir stops the receiver so start the receiver again
    previousTransmittion = millis(); // set the record for latest transmittion to the currnt time  
      
    // toggle the yellow light
    digitalWrite(yellowLight, toggleYellow);
    toggleYellow = not toggleYellow;
  }
  
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) { // if we have received an IR signal
    Serial.println (String(results.value, HEX)); //display HEX results 
    if (String(results.value, DEC) == "1367857")
    {
      Serial.println("correct code");
      // toggle the green light
      digitalWrite(greenLight, toggleGreen);
      toggleGreen = not toggleGreen;
    }
    irrecv.resume(); // it stops the receiver when something's received so we muct resume the ir receiver     
 }
}
```

// End of sketch 1

The receiver is on pin 8 and, button on pin 13 and transmitting LED is always on pin 3.

No issues there.

However, when I use the same concepts on a larger-scale project, a strange problem occurs. Once one of the Arduinos has sent some IR, the receiver no longer works. After every line of code which sends IR, I follow it with `irrecv.enableIRIn();`, and after every time it receives code I have the line `irrecv.resume();`. I can't work out what the problem is. It's very long, but the full code is below:

// Start of code 2

```
// include the library code:
#include <LiquidCrystal.h> // For the LCD
#include <IRremote.h> // For the IR communication
#include <PCM.h> // For the audio output 

const unsigned char gunShot[] PROGMEM = {}; // In the program this contains a huge array of notes, I removed them to save space

const unsigned char gunClick[] PROGMEM = {}; // In the program this contains a huge array of notes, I removed them to save space


// Declare consants for pins
const int rs = A0, en = A1, d4 = A2, d5 = A3, d6 = A4, d7 = A5; // State constants for all the pins used for the LCD
const int trigger = 13;
const int redLight = 7;
const int magReader1 = 9;
const int magReader2 = 10;
const int speaker = 11;
const int healButton = 12;
const int receiver = 8;
const int muzzle = 2;

// Declare constants for gameplay
const int timeBetweenShots = 800; //(in 1000ths of a second)

const int healAmount = 100;

const int medicAmmo = 16;
const int assultAmmo = 31;
const int sniperAmmo = 1;

const int medicDamage = 30;
const int assultDamage = 23;
const int sniperDamage = 75;

const int playerNumber = 4;

// Declare all valiables
int timesKilledByTeam1 = 0; // I would loved to have used an array here, but for some reason an array broke the program
int timesKilledByTeam2 = 0;
int timesKilledByTeam3 = 0;
int timesKilledByTeam4 = 0;
int timesKilledByTeam5 = 0;
int timesKilledByTeam6 = 0;
int timesKilledByTeam7 = 0;
int timesKilledByTeam8 = 0;

String receivedCode = ""; // Store the received code in a string variable
bool gameDone = false;

bool semiCanShoot = true;
bool gunShouldClick = true;

int health = 100;
int gameMode = 1; // 1=TDM, 2=FFA, 3=LTS, 4=LPS
bool respawn = true;
int teamOrPlayer = playerNumber;
int loadStatus; // 0 is no mag, 1 is mag1, 2 is mag2

int mag1Ammo; // Current ammo in mag1
int mag2Ammo; // Current ammo in mag2
int maxAmmo; // Ammo in one mag for the selected class
int damage; // Damage this player is inflicting per shot

long int timeOfFlash = 0;
long int timeOfMuzzle = 0;
long int timeOfLastShot = 0;
long int loopTimer = 0;

int gameStartTime; // In seconds so no need for long int
//int secondsRemaining;
int gameDuration;

int playerClass = 0; // 0=Medic, 1=Asult, 2=Snipr

int shootCode;

IRsend irsend; //Setup the IR transmitter
IRrecv irrecv(receiver); //create a new instance of receiver
decode_results results;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

void SetupClass()
{    
    switch (playerClass)
    {
        case (0):
          maxAmmo = medicAmmo;
          damage = medicDamage;
          break;
        case (1):
          maxAmmo = assultAmmo;
          damage = assultDamage;
          break;
        case (2):
          maxAmmo = sniperAmmo;
          damage = sniperDamage;
          break;
    }
    mag1Ammo = maxAmmo;
    mag2Ammo = maxAmmo;
}

// Define subroutines
//void QuickDisplayUpdate(int ammo, int secondsRemaining, int loadStatus, int health) // During a game, to save unnecessary computation, only update the things that might have changed during the game
void QuickDisplayUpdate()
{
    lcd.setCursor(11,0);
    if((gameDuration - (millis() / 1000 - gameStartTime)) / 60 < 10)
    {
      lcd.print("0");
      lcd.setCursor(12,0);
    }
    lcd.print(String((gameDuration - (millis() / 1000 - gameStartTime)) / 60));

    lcd.setCursor(14,0);
    if((gameDuration - (millis() / 1000 - gameStartTime)) % 60 < 10) 
    {
      lcd.print("0");
      lcd.setCursor(15,0); 
    }
    lcd.print(String((gameDuration - (millis() / 1000 - gameStartTime)) % 60));


    lcd.setCursor(7,1); // Put the / in as it might have been removed from a previous "Reload!"
    lcd.print("/");
    
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    if (loadStatus == 0) lcd.print("Reload!");
    else if (loadStatus == 1)
    {
      lcd.print("Mag" + String(loadStatus) + ":");
      lcd.setCursor(5,1);
      if (mag1Ammo < 10)
      {
        lcd.print("0");
        lcd.setCursor(6,1);
      }
      lcd.print(String(mag1Ammo));
    }
    else
    {
      lcd.print("Mag" + String(loadStatus) + ":");
      lcd.setCursor(5,1);
      if (mag2Ammo < 10)
      {
        lcd.print("0");
        lcd.setCursor(6,1);
      }
      lcd.print(String(mag2Ammo));
    }



    lcd.setCursor(13,1);
    if(health < 100) 
    {
      lcd.print(" ");
      lcd.setCursor(14,1); 
      if(health < 10) 
        {
          lcd.print(" ");
          lcd.setCursor(15,1); 
        }
    }
   
    lcd.print(String(health));
}

void FullDisplayUpdate(int teamOrPlayer)
{
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    switch (gameMode)
    {
        case (1):
          lcd.print("TDM");
          break;
        case (2):
          lcd.print("FFA");
          break;
        case (3):
          lcd.print("LTS");
          break;
        case (4):
          lcd.print("LPS");
          break;
    }

    lcd.setCursor(3,0);
    lcd.print(String(teamOrPlayer));
    
    lcd.setCursor(5,0);
    switch (playerClass)
    {
        case (0):
          lcd.print("Medic");
          break;
        case (1):
          lcd.print("Asult");
          break;
        case (2):
          lcd.print("Snipr");
          break;
    }

    lcd.setCursor(11,0);
    if((gameDuration - (millis() / 1000 - gameStartTime)) / 60 < 10)
    {
      lcd.print("0");
      lcd.setCursor(12,0);
    }
    lcd.print(String((gameDuration - (millis() / 1000 - gameStartTime)) / 60) + ":");

    lcd.setCursor(14,0);
    if((gameDuration - (millis() / 1000 - gameStartTime)) % 60 < 10) 
    {
      lcd.print("0");
      lcd.setCursor(15,0); 
    }
    lcd.print(String((gameDuration - (millis() / 1000 - gameStartTime)) % 60));



    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    if (loadStatus == 0) lcd.print("Reload!");
    else if (loadStatus == 1)
    {
      lcd.print("Mag" + String(loadStatus) + ":");
      lcd.setCursor(5,1);
      if (mag1Ammo < 10)
      {
        lcd.print("0");
        lcd.setCursor(6,1);
      }
      lcd.print(String(mag1Ammo));
    }
    else
    {
      lcd.print("Mag" + String(loadStatus) + ":");
      lcd.setCursor(5,1);
      if (mag2Ammo < 10)
      {
        lcd.print("0");
        lcd.setCursor(6,1);
      }
      lcd.print(String(mag2Ammo));
    }


    lcd.setCursor(8,1);
    if (maxAmmo < 10)
    {
      lcd.print("0");
      lcd.setCursor(9,1);
    }
    lcd.print(String(maxAmmo));
    



    lcd.setCursor(11,1);
    lcd.print("H:" + String(health));

    
}


void Play()
{
  gameDone = false; // When the game starts, the game isn't done
  
  FullDisplayUpdate(teamOrPlayer); // Fully update the display before the game starts

  // Setup the shoot code
  if(damage > 9) shootCode = (String(teamOrPlayer) + String(damage) ).toInt(); 
  else shootCode = (String(teamOrPlayer) + "0" + String(damage)).toInt();
   
  // Wait until either a start or cancel code is recieved
  Serial.println("wait");
  receivedCode = "";
  //irrecv.enableIRIn(); // sending ir stops the receiver so start the receiver again
  while (receivedCode.length() != 2 && receivedCode.length() != 4)
  {    
    if (irrecv.decode(&results)) 
    {
      receivedCode = String(results.value, DEC); // Store the received code in a variable when we have received an IR signal
      irrecv.resume(); // Remove the code
    }
  }
  

  Serial.println("code: " + receivedCode);

  gameStartTime = millis() / 1000; // Set the game start time in seconds

  if (String(receivedCode) == "50") // If the received code was starting code (50) then play
  {
      Serial.println("strt, dur: " + String(gameDuration) + "team: " + String(teamOrPlayer));
      
      while (gameDone == false) // Repeat until the game is done
      {    
          //Serial.println("Game loop");

          CheckForIR(); // Check for an IR code as often as possible
          
          if (playerClass == 0) // Only check for heal button if they are a medic
          {
            if (not digitalRead(healButton) && millis() > timeOfLastShot + timeBetweenShots) // If they are pressing the heal button and it's been enought time since last shot
            {
                Serial.println("heal bttn");
                if (loadStatus == 1 && mag1Ammo == maxAmmo) // If mag1 is in and it's full
                {
                    Serial.println("heal 1");
                    irsend.sendNEC((String(teamOrPlayer) + "00").toInt(), 32); // Send the heal code
                    //irrecv.enableIRIn(); // sending ir stops the receiver so start the receiver again
                    digitalWrite(muzzle, 1); // Turn on the muzzle flash
                    timeOfMuzzle = millis(); // Set the time of the muzzle turning on
                    //startPlayback(healShot, sizeof(healShot)); // Play  heal sound
                    mag1Ammo = 0; // Empty the current mag
                }
                else if (loadStatus == 2 && mag2Ammo == maxAmmo) // If mag2 is in and it's full
                {
                    Serial.println("heal 1");
                    irsend.sendNEC((String(teamOrPlayer) + "00").toInt(), 32); // Send the heal code
                    //irrecv.enableIRIn(); // sending ir stops the receiver so start the receiver again
                    digitalWrite(muzzle, 1); // Turn on the muzzle flash
                    timeOfMuzzle = millis(); // Set the time of the muzzle turning on
                    //startPlayback(healShot, sizeof(healShot)); // Play  heal sound
                    mag2Ammo = 0; // Empty the current mag
                }
            }
          }
          
          CheckForIR();
          
          if (not digitalRead(trigger) && (millis() > timeOfLastShot + timeBetweenShots)) // If the trigger is pulled and it's been long enough since last shot
          {
              Serial.println("sht bttn");
              if (loadStatus == 1 && mag1Ammo > 0) // If mag1 is in and it has ammo
              {
                  if (playerClass != 0 || semiCanShoot == true) // They can shoot if they are on full auto or if semi can shoot
                  {
                      Serial.println("1 sht");
                      irsend.sendNEC(shootCode, 32); // Send the shoot code 
                      irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
                      digitalWrite(muzzle, 1); // Turn on the muzzle flash
                      timeOfMuzzle = millis(); // Set the time of the muzzle turning on
                      mag1Ammo = mag1Ammo - 1; // Reduce ammo of current mag by one  
                      semiCanShoot = false; // Once they have shot, they cannot shoot again if on semi mode
                      startPlayback(gunShot, sizeof(gunShot)); // Play shot
                      Serial.println("1 sht done");
                  }                     
              }
              
              else if (loadStatus == 2 && mag2Ammo > 0) // If mag2 is in and it has ammo
              {
                  if (playerClass != 0 || semiCanShoot == true) // They can shoot if they are on full auto or if semi can shoot
                  {
                      Serial.println("2 sht");
                      irsend.sendNEC(shootCode, 32); // Send the shoot code
                      irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
                      digitalWrite(muzzle, 1); // Turn on the muzzle flash
                      timeOfMuzzle = millis(); // Set the time of the muzzle turning on
                      mag2Ammo = mag2Ammo - 1; // Reduce ammo of current mag by one
                      semiCanShoot = false; // Once they have shot, they cannot shoot again if on semi mode
                      startPlayback(gunShot, sizeof(gunShot)); // Play shot
                      Serial.println("2 sht done");
                  }                            
              }
    
              else if (gunShouldClick) // (If no mag in OR no ammo in the mag that's in) AND gun should click
              {
                  Serial.println("clik");
                  startPlayback(gunClick, sizeof(gunClick)); // Play click sound
                  gunShouldClick = false; // Gun shouldn't click again until they releace trigger
              }
              timeOfLastShot = millis(); // Update the time of last shot
              Serial.println("shot done");
          }

          CheckForIR();
    
          // Check for if the gun should click again and if player can shoot again if on semi mode  
          if (digitalRead(trigger)) semiCanShoot = true; // If they are not holding the trigger, they can shoot again if on semi mode
          if (digitalRead(healButton) && digitalRead(trigger)) gunShouldClick = true; // If they are not holding the trigger or the heal button, the gun should click again when they do hold it again

          CheckForIR();

          // If the LEDs have been on for long enough, turn them off        
          if (millis() > timeOfFlash + 50) digitalWrite(redLight, 0); // Turn off the red LEDs if they have been on for enough time
          if (millis() > timeOfMuzzle + 50) digitalWrite(muzzle, 0); // Turn off the muzzle if it's been on for enough time
          
          CheckForIR();

          if (millis() > loopTimer + 250) // Some things need to be done less often, so do that to save time so IR receive checks can be done more frequently
          {
              loopTimer = millis();
              
              QuickDisplayUpdate(); // Quick update the display after every loop
  
              CheckForIR();
              
              // Update the loadStatus variable depending on the mag detector inputs
              if (!digitalRead(magReader1) && digitalRead(magReader2))
              {
                  loadStatus = 1;
                  mag2Ammo = maxAmmo; // Refil mag2 if mag one is in
              }
              else if (!digitalRead(magReader2) && digitalRead(magReader1)) 
              {
                  loadStatus = 2;
                  mag1Ammo = maxAmmo; // Refil mag1 if mag two is in
              }
              else loadStatus = 0;
  
              CheckForIR();
  
              // Check to see if the game has reached the time limit
              if (gameDuration - (millis() / 1000 - gameStartTime) < 1)
              {
                Serial.println("tm up");
                gameDone = true;
              }
          }
          
      } // Game is done
      
  } // If the received code wasn't the starting code then cancel the game and return to waiting menu
}  


void CheckForIR()
{
  //Serial.println("check");
  //irrecv.enableIRIn(); // sending ir stops the receiver so start the receiver again
  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) // If there is a code
  {   
      receivedCode = String(results.value, DEC); // Store the received code in a string variable
      Serial.println(receivedCode);
      irrecv.resume(); // Remove the code
      if (receivedCode.length() == 3) // If the received code has length 3, we have been shot
      {          
          Serial.println ("shot"); //display shot code
          if (receivedCode.substring(0,1) != String(teamOrPlayer)) // Only continue if the shooter is on another team
          {
              Serial.println ("another team");
              digitalWrite(redLight, 1); // Turn on the red lights                                
              health = health - (receivedCode.substring(1, 3).toInt()); // Reduce health by incoming damage, if it's an enemy heal it won't have an effect
          }
          else if (receivedCode.substring(1, 3).toInt() == 0)
          {
            Serial.println("heal");
            health = health + healAmount; // Heal if they are a teammate and they are doing 0 damage
          }
          
      }
  
      if (health > 100) health = 100; // Set back to 100, cannot be on over 100 health
      else if (health < 1)
      {
          Serial.println ("died");
          switch(receivedCode.substring(0,1).toInt()) // Increment's the killer's kills by one
          {
            case (1):
              timesKilledByTeam1++;
              break;
            case (2):
              timesKilledByTeam2++;
              break;
            case (3):
              timesKilledByTeam3++;
              break;
            case (4):
              timesKilledByTeam4++;
              break;
            case (5):
              timesKilledByTeam5++;
              break;
            case (6):
              timesKilledByTeam6++;
              break;
            case (7):
              timesKilledByTeam7++;
              break;
            case (8):
              timesKilledByTeam8++;
              break;
          }
  
          health = 100; // Reset the health
          mag1Ammo = maxAmmo; // Refil the mags
          mag2Ammo = maxAmmo;
          
          // Update the LCD
          lcd.clear();
          lcd.setCursor(0,0);
          lcd.print("You died!");
          lcd.setCursor(0,1);
          lcd.print("Return to base");
  
          if (respawn == false) gameDone = true; // If playing one life gamemode, end game
          else // Otherwise wait until respawn code is recieved
          {
              //irrecv.enableIRIn(); // sending ir stops the receiver so start the receiver again
              while ((receivedCode != "50") && (gameDuration - (millis() / 1000 - gameStartTime) > 1)) // Keep looking for IR siginal until it's 50 or the time's up
              {
                  //irrecv.enableIRIn(); // sending ir stops the receiver so start the receiver again
                  if (irrecv.decode(&results)) // if we have received an IR signal
                  {
                      receivedCode = String(results.value, DEC); // Store the received code in received code variable
                      irrecv.resume();
                  }
              }                                    
          }
          FullDisplayUpdate(teamOrPlayer); // Reset the LCD to gameplay mode
          
      }
  }
}



void setup() 
{ 
  lcd.begin(16, 2); // Set up the LCD's number of columns and rows
  Serial.begin(9600); // Send code at 9600 bits per second
  irrecv.enableIRIn(); // Start the receiver
  pinMode(trigger, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(magReader1, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(magReader2, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(healButton, INPUT_PULLUP);
}

void loop() // Repeat while looking for game (between games)
{
    Serial.println("\nlp");
    digitalWrite(redLight, 1); // Turn on the lights to show player isn't playing at the moment
    
    // Print waiting screen to LCD
    lcd.clear();
    lcd.setCursor(0,0);
    lcd.print("Awaiting start");
    lcd.setCursor(0,1);
    lcd.print("Player: " + String(playerNumber));

    //irrecv.resume();//  NOT YET TESTED
    //irrecv.enableIRIn(); // sending ir stops the receiver so start the receiver again
    while (not irrecv.decode(&results)) // wait until we have received an IR signal 
    { 
        // Transmit previous game data while we wait
        //Serial.println("wait");
    }
    
    receivedCode = String(results.value, DEC); // Store the received code in a string variable
    Serial.println(receivedCode); //display results 
    irrecv.resume();
    
    if (receivedCode.length() == 4) // It was a sucessfull transmission if the recieved code was 4 characters long
    {
      playerClass = receivedCode.substring(3, 4).toInt(); // Set the class to the recieved class
      Serial.println("clss: " + String(playerClass));      
      SetupClass();
      
      gameDuration = 180 * (receivedCode.substring(1,2).toInt() + 1); // Set the time remaining and game duration to the received time
      Serial.println("tm lft" + String((gameDuration - (millis() / 1000 - gameStartTime))) + ", gameDuration: " + String(gameDuration));

      // Reset the death counter as a new game is starting
      int timesKilledByTeam1 = 0;
      int timesKilledByTeam2 = 0;
      int timesKilledByTeam3 = 0;
      int timesKilledByTeam4 = 0;
      int timesKilledByTeam5 = 0;
      int timesKilledByTeam6 = 0;
      int timesKilledByTeam7 = 0;
      int timesKilledByTeam8 = 0;
      
      health = 100;
      
      switch (receivedCode.substring(0, 1).toInt()) // Do operations based on the received game mode
      {
          case (1): // TDM            
            Serial.println("TDM");
            gameMode = 1;
            teamOrPlayer = receivedCode.substring(2, 3).toInt();
            respawn = true;
            Play(); // Call play with received team and respawn on
            break;
            
          case (2): //FFA
            gameMode = 2;
            Serial.println("FFA");
            respawn = true;
            teamOrPlayer = playerNumber;
            Play(); // Call play with player number and respawn on
            break;
            
          case (3): // LTS
            gameMode = 3;
            Serial.println("LTS");
            respawn = false;
            teamOrPlayer = receivedCode.substring(2, 3).toInt();
            //Play(); // Call play with received team and respawn off
            break;
            
          case (4): // LPS
            gameMode = 4;
            Serial.println("LPS");
            respawn = false;
            teamOrPlayer = playerNumber;
            //Play(); // Call play with player numebr and respawn off
            break;
            
          default:
            Serial.println("Unknown Gamemode");
            break;
      }
      
    }  
    
}
```

// End of code 2

I know this code is a mess, I should not be using global variables and there should be more subroutines, but I wrote most of it before remembering about them :/

If I run the sketch and don't "shoot" on that reset, the code works fully as intended, but the "times killed by player x" variables section I haven't got to yet.

Extra information which I don't think is relevant:

There is a third Arduino which allows you to choose a code and send it, or send the code "50". This is the "base" which someone must return to in order to respawn, as it's the only thing which can send the code "50". The codes it can send are explained below:

It sends a 4-digit number, but it's read as 4 separate numbers, for example, consider the code "rspq". The r is the game mode (1=team respawn, 2=free for all, 3=last team standing, 4=last player standing), s is the duration of the game (time(s) = 3 * (s + 1), resulting in possible times of 3,6,9...30), p is the team that that player is on (when playing a team game)(when not playing a team game it just uses the player ID stored on that particular gun) and q is the class (1=medic, 2=assault, 3=sniper).

There is a lot to say so if you have any questions just ask.

Any help/ideas would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile with the plain "IRRemote" library from the manager, at least not with the version I have installed.  Rather than guess at which library/fork/version, I figured I'd ask, which is it?

Comment: I have IRremote by shirriff, z3t0 and ArminJo. I just updated it to 3.0.0 although I'm not sure what version I had before updating, 2.6 or something... It now doesn't compile :/, do you know why that is? Thanks

Comment: I have used the website: https://github.com/Arduino-IRremote/Arduino-IRremote to update my code to the 3.0 version but there is still one line which returns an error: IRsend.sendNECMSB(shootCode, 32); gives the error: expected unqualified-id before '.' token. Do you know how to fix that or will I need to send you the whole sketch again now I have updated it?

Comment: I'm not sure I want to go down that rabbit hole in comments.  I just needed to know how to get your original code to compile.  I installed 2.6.1 and it compiles.

Comment: Okay, 2.6.1 sounds likely, but once an Arduino sends an IR code, it no longer receives them even though I have the enable ir line in it. Any ideas?

Comment: That sort of thing goes in the question.  Which you already have in the question.  Which I've read already.  What I'm wondering is exactly where in your code does it stop?  If you have this connected to serial you can sprinkle your code with `Serial.println(__LINE__);` see line numbers print.  Move them around until you've narrowed down the exact line (or lines if its stuck in a loop in code you wrote) where the code stops executing.

Comment: The code never gets stuck as such, after the "game" has ended it returns to the main loop and works fine. Even if I have send IR in that loop, the code doesn't get stuck somewhere, it just disables the receiver so more IR cannot be received.

Comment: Well, I have it compiled and uploaded to a board, but I have no practical way to test it to even see what you're seeing.  I'd replace the IR receiving code with Serial input for testing, but I expect having done that the problem will be gone or different.  If you were on IRC I'd take you through transforming the code into something cleaner, but there's not really a lot I can do here in this format.  I do think it's nice that you want to do something for your cousins though.  If you cut this down into something more managable someone (maybe me) will have useful input.

Comment: Thanks, I tried using the serial input and as you expected, the problem disappeared. What's IRC? The problem is when I cut it down into a smaller program I don't have the same problem, I'll try reducing the contents of the program bit by bit (removing sound, then LCD etc) to see if I can identify what makes it work in my small sketch but not the large project. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the audio aspect of my larger program was interfering with the IR receiver, as every time I send IR I also play a sound. It was the sound which was stopping the receiver, not the IR transmitter. When I removed the sound from the sketch, it worked as intended. Thanks timemage for your help.